# Spock set list as parameter by using table

Tags: java, testing, groovy, junit, spock

There is a simply class:

```
class Person {
   private int age;
   private String name;

   public String getName(){return this.name;}
   public int getAge(){return this.age;}
   public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
   public void setAge(int age){this.age = age;}
 }
```

and I have a methods `getPersonNameWithPrefix()` and `getPeopleNames()` in `SearchPeople` interface with implement in `SearchPeopleImpl`:

```
class SearchPeopleImpl implements SearchPeople {

   public String getPersonNameWithPrefix(Person person){
      return "prefix" + person.getName();
   }

   public List<String> getPeopleNames(List<Person> peopleList){
      return peopleList.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

}
```

I want to use parameters in my test and it looks like:

```
def 'test Person name'(){
        given:
            def searchPeople = new SearchPeopleImpl ()
            def person = Mock(Person){
                getName() >> a
            }
        when:
            def name = searchPeople.getPersonNameWithPrefix(person)
        then:
            name == b
        where:
            a         |       b
            "AA"      |       "prefixAA"
            "BB"      |       "prefixBB"
            "CC"      |       "prefixCC"
    }
```

It works well but I have a problem with test my second method. How is it possible to put list of elements into `table` (in `where` section), use it as method parameter and then expect another list of objects? I mean that I want to declare a few list of `Person` objects and then check that method returns correct list of `Strings`

@UPDATE
So is there any way to do something like:

```
   def 'test getting persons names'(){
        given:
            def searchPeople = new SearchPeopleImpl()
        when:
            def names = searchPeople.getPeopleNames(a)
        then:
            names == b
        where:
            a                                                                  |       b
            ["AA","BB"].collect{ x -> Mock(Person){ getName() >> x } }         |       [["AA", "BB"]]
            ["CC"].collect{ x -> Mock(Person){ getName() >> x } }              |       [["CC"]]
            ["DD","EE","FD"].collect{ x -> Mock(Person){ getName() >> x } }    |       [["DD","EE","FD"]]
    }
```

or:

```
def 'check double2 return value'(){
    given:
        def searchPeople = new SearchPeopleImpl()
    when:
        def names = searchPeople.getPeopleNames(a)
    then:
        names == b
    where:
        people1 << [
                ["AA","BB"].collect{ x ->
                    Mock(Person){
                        getName() >> x
                    }
                }
        ]
        people2 << [
                ["CC"].collect{ x ->
                    Mock(Person){
                        getName() >> x
                    }
                }
        ]

        names1 << [["AA", "BB"]]
        names2 << [["CC"]]

        a               |       b
        people1         |       names1
        people2         |       names2
}
```

I just want to use table to set parameters but it is possible that i am totally wrong.

@UPDATE there is an error:

```
check double return value[0](com.test.myPlugin.api.SearchPeopleSpec)  Time elapsed: 0.125 sec  <<< FAILURE!
Condition not satisfied:

names == b
|    |  |
|    |  [[AA, BB]]
|    false
[AA, BB]
```

and there is the same error for every row.

Comment: It is bad practice to mock simple pojos the same effect can be achieved by using the bean constructor, e.g., `["AA","BB"].collect{ new Person(name: it) }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instance of `List` can be used in exactly the same way in data-drive testing. Have a look at the following example:

```
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    def 'test getting persons names'() {
        given:
        def searchPeople = new SearchPeopleImpl()

        when:
        def result = searchPeople.getPeopleNames(names)

        then:
        result == expectedNames

        where:
        names << [
            ["AA", "BB"].collect { n ->
            Mock(Person) {
                getName() >> n
            }
        }
        ]
        expectedNames << [["AA", "BB"]]
    }
}
```

Note the double parens in where block. It must specified this way since if only single pair would be used every single argument will be passed separately instead of passing the whole list.

Comment: @tombobby, your first example works well, when using this syntax no additional parens in `b` are required, just use single. Second example is a mix of two approaches which is invalid by design.

Comment: Unfortunately first solution doesn't work (I edited my post again and put there details)

Comment: @tombobby, read my previous comment please once again. In the first solution you don't need double parens for `b`. Just use single, so: `["AA", "BB"]`, `["CC"]`, `["DD","EE","FD"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually combine the data tables with variable assignments ([docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_combining_data_tables_data_pipes_and_variable_assignments)) which provides a much cleaner test:

```
def 'test getting persons names'(){
    given:
    def searchPeople = new SearchPeopleImpl()

    when:
    def names = searchPeople.getPeopleNames(input)

    then:
    names == expected

    where:
    a                   |       expected
    ["AA","BB"]         |       [["AA", "BB"]]
    ["CC"]              |       [["CC"]]
    ["DD","EE","FD"]    |       [["DD","EE","FD"]]

    input = a.collect{ new Person(name: it) }
}
```

Furthermore, only use `Mock` if you need the validation, e.g., `1 * mock.method()` if you only use it as a collaborator use `Stub` instead to make your intent clear. Also, never mock simple POJOs when you can just construct them via bean constructor.

Comment: Could you put example how to put a few value to object? In this example  how to put `name` (as you did) and `age` to every object?

Comment: @tombobby I don't understand what you want? Are you asking about this: http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_initializing_beans_with_named_parameters_and_the_default_constructor You can do something like this `[[name: "AA", age: 18], [name: "BB", age: 20]].collect {new Person(it)}`